# Is this picture of Rachel Dolezal reading a book called "How to be Black" genuine?

Tags: photography

This picture of [Rachel Dolezal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rachel_Dolezal) has been making the rounds online. Is it genuine?

[image]

[Ijreview](http://www.ijreview.com/2015/06/344564-the-book-that-rachel-dolezal-is-holding-has-some-thinking-this-may-be-the-best-political-photo-ever/?utm_source=Facebook&utm_medium=Owned&utm_term=conservativedaily&utm_campaign=Politics), where it was featured, isn't sure if the image is fake or real.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The image turns out to be photoshopped.

Apparently, that picture has been tweeted recently by a columnist called [Jonah Goldberg](https://twitter.com/JonahNRO) [here](https://twitter.com/JonahNRO/status/609892710170935296/photo/1) on 14 June 2015 and went viral:

[image]

After rigorous search online, an old occurrence of the photo was found which was [posted](https://www.flickr.com/photos/theeasterner/12473640784/in/photolist-tCj33n-k1fMou-k1fEQ9-k1fBhh-k1ft7j-k1e8KV-k1d5pa-k1e1X6-uxuHu9-uyWYTM-tBZGbe-uj1G6t-uyu2k8-ug99ow-tzZmkz-uwLMqy-tBk9mD-uxSDxN-uzfeES-bSV9yH/) on flickr on February 11, 2014:

[image]

So, if we want to match the images together, it would look like this:

[image]

The photo in the album [Rachel Dolezal: Tangled (Karissa)](https://www.flickr.com/photos/theeasterner/sets/72157640864760544) was also accompanied with several other images belonging to the event.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Isn't it crazy how she was able to stand in exactly the same pose sans what she was holding? That takes skill!

Comment: Something about her hand in the edited photo looks off, like it's clearly been modified.

Comment: @Scimonster [She has a finger missing (mostly)!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9OfrC.png)

Comment: I agree with scimonster.  Her thumb is 'cut off' on her hand where the book is 'held'.  It's like the book cuts straight through her hand, with no sign of a thumb which would need to be used to hold the book up.